# Why the inkscape circle drawing automaticlly draw a quarter circle instead of whole circle?

Tags: inkscape

Why the Inkscape circle drawing automatically draw a quarter circle instead of the whole circle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inkscape will remember the last configuration for creating a circle. If you look on the toolbar after selecting or creating a circle, you'll see three icons, one for closed arc:

[image: closed arc]

one for open arc:

[image: open arc]

and finally, full circle.

If circle is previously selected, and you wish to create an arc, click and change the start or end values to "activate" the other two icons. Clicking full circle icon grays out the three icons.

[image: full circle]

Similar presentation available on [this SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/drawing-a-three-quarter-circle-in-inkscape?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you so much,dude. I got it