# In my Inkscape, why is there is a horizontal line appearing every time I draw a circle?

Tags: inkscape

I think it is because of a previous setting or user behaviour, but I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Check the tool bar for a set of icons: "pie," arc and circle. If you have the pie selected, it will close the circle with radii.

Note also the start and end angle dialog boxes.

[image: partial circle]

[Duplicate answer here.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/129642/why-the-inkscape-circle-drawing-automaticlly-draw-a-quarter-circle-instead-of-wh?rq=1)